# How to get respond object in service?

Tags: nestjs

I want to use this package https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node/blob/master/README.md in nestjs project.

How to get respond object in service for init module ?

```
i18n.init(req, res);
```

For request, I found it https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass it from the controller

```
import {Response, Request} from 'express'

@Get(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
  myService.method(req, res);
}
```